# Is there any way to add visualization in SSRS report to blurred out unnecessary fields?

Tags: reporting-services

I have created the SSRS report which contains CarID, RegistrationNo, CarID_creation_date and Reg_Date.
Also I have created the parameters for dates by which I can select the date range. But how can I create a report in which if I enter only CarID then only CarID_creation_date should get activate and other field gets blurred out/disabled, and vice versa.
I have tried with a query so from backend using case statement and its working fine, but I wanted to add this visualization in SSRS report, so how can I add the same? [Report_Design_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhmHK.jpg)

Currently using below code:

`IF @CarID='' and  @RegID=''
Begin SELECT * FROM Car_Details END
ELSE
IF @CarID=<>'' and  @RegID='' Begin SELECT * FROM Car_Details where CarID_creation_date Between @CarID_Start_Date and @CarID_End_Date
ELSE
IF @CarID='' and  @RegID=<>'' Begin SELECT * FROM Car_Details where Reg_date Between @Reg_Start_Date and @Reg_End_Date
END
IF @CarID=<>'' and  @RegID=<>'' Begin SELECT * FROM Car_Details where CarID_creation_date Between @CarID_Start_Date and @CarID_End_Date AND Reg_date Between @Reg_Start_Date and @Reg_End_Date
END`

Comment: Mystery Abbreviation SSRS Reports ?   Had you said [TPS reports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TPS_report), that would have been fine.

Comment: SQL Server Reporting Services

Comment: 1. You can create the report calculation field, use same case concept to display the respective fields. Or 2. Use blur images and set its visibility based on display fields

Comment: Have you considered using conditions to switch visibility on/off? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/hide-an-item-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You cannot conditionally turn parameters on and off in SSRS.
The only way you can do this is if a value is entered in Carid, then it can look at only the dates for car_id_creation_date. You can do this in your datasource - if you are suing SQL as your backend, you could make your where clause to be something like this :

```
where 
(isnull(@carid,'')<>'' and sometable.datecolumn between @carid_creationstart and @carid_creationend)
or
(isnull(@reg_no,'')<>'' and sometable.datecolumn2 between @reg_no_creationstart and @reg_no_creationend)
```

in your SSRS front end, you can set the parameter to be set to be NULL and blank

The alternative is to have a drop down parameter called "Category" and then make the select values as Car_id and Reg_id. Then you will have only one set of date parameter that can be used for both categories.

so your where statement will be something like

```
where

(@category = 'car_id' and sometable.datecolumn between @start_date and @end_date)
or
(@category = 'reg_id' and sometable.datecolumn2 between @start_date and @end_date)
```

Comment: Hi Harry,

Currently I am using the If - Else condition in SQL query.
That code working fine as you have mentioned in first statement. 
But I am looking for any condition by which I can make the date parts visible/hide as per the values entered in CarID or RegID.
Or alternatively is there any way to add checkbox kind option for dates, on which the data will get displayed.

Comment: Like I answered above.. you cannot hide parameters conditionally..  you can use the second option above.. make the user select a category and then the dates will relate to that category.. report will look tidier as it has only 3 parameters in total. I'd go with the second option in my answer if I were you

Comment: Yes that is the best way if user wants to select only one of the entity (either CarID or RegID). But in my case for some users, both the fields needs to be selected and thats the roadblock here.

Comment: make your category multi select so you can select both if need be.. change your where clause to handle multi select parameters